# Javascript not working inside a website on IIS7.5 - Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have deployed a website in IIS 7.5 on windows server 2008 R2.
The javascript runs fine when i run the application from my local machine , but when deployed on IIS 7.5 , it fails to run the javascript part of my menu .
please help me solve this problem.

onclick="ShowSubMenuUser();

Above is the code which doesn't fires when i click on my menu item .
The function contains the following code :

```
function ShowSubMenuUser()
{
    document.getElementById("ctl00_trsubViewUser").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_trsubRegisterUser").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_trSubMenuItemFooterUser").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_trPOReport").style.display = "block";
}
```

This code runs fine on Local Machine as well as in Visual Studio , but on Server when i click on the menu , nothing happens .

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Windows Server 2008 R2 runs IIS 7.5, it's part of the operating system.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? You have to describe exactly what goes wrong? Check your developer console in the browser for exceptions.

Comment: It is 7.5 , sorry for the mistake

Comment: Nothing happens , when i click on the Menu Link . the javascript not runs and nothing happens . it should show the menu opening on click , as it does on my local machine . UNABLE TO FIGURE WHAT'S WRONG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your user control name.

ctl00_trsubViewUser

The CT100_ may have a different name on localhost and on the server.

Change the user control dropped on the parent page to have ClientIDMode="Static" then the control name will not change.

View your source when rendering the page on the server and without client id mode you should see the name of the control is not the same as on localhost.